# Where are magento 1.5 product reviews stored?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, magento

In my magento 1.5 webshop I've re-created some products because it seemed the easiest way to convert configurable products to simple products.
anyways, now I want to move the reviews to the new products but i cannot find them within the database.
Does anyone know where they are stored so that i can move them to the correct products?

-thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The table you're interested in is `review`.  This table holds the relationship between the review itself and the product.  The `review` table has a column named `entity_pk_value` that references the primary key of the product being reviewed.

Replace the value in the `entity_pk_value` column with the new product id and all of the reviews *should* be moved across.